# How to get the title attribute of a input element? - webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How to get the attribute of Title in the input element

```
<input type="image" title="Previous Page">
<input type="image" title="First Page">
<input type="image" title="Next Page">
<input type="image" title="Last Page">
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What have you tried? Typically something like the following should work:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
String title = element.getAttribute("title");
```

Comment: The above code will only return the first element with tagName "input" inside your <html />

Comment: Great! I used get_attribute() in my Python code and, to my surprise, it worked! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by Jim Evans is the correct one imo, but for a more specific one i'd advise something like below. Remeber that copy-pasta might not work and you need to change something to be able to work on your full HTML.

```java
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    if (element.getAttribute("type").equals("image")) {
        System.out.println(element.getAttribute("title"));
    }
}
```

The above code will loop for all the  in your webpage that are from type="image" and print on the console the "title" attribute of each one of those.

Still thing you should vote Jim's answer as the correct one though.

Comment: i'm kinda curious to know why do you think Jim's answer as the correct one?

Comment: The question was: "How to get the attribute of Title in the input element?", to me that sounds like a better answer when you google it or smth.

Comment: All i did was work on that solution and implement in a way that suits more the scenario prompted on the question itself, either way just hope one of those have worked for you :D

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to identify the input element from which you want to get the value of the attribute **title** .

Then something like the following must work.

```
element.getAttribute("title");
```

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple and work for as well.

```
String title = driver.getTitle();
```